# Regex matching a non-empty string that is not equal to certain value

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I'm trying to write a regex to match any string that is not empty or equals to  `www`.

Example:

```
www => don't match
ww => match
adwww => match
wwwad => match
abcde => match
```

My regex:

```
(.+)(www)
```

How  can I fix my regex?

Comment: something like  `str!="www"` or `!"www".equals(str)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a lookahead based regex:

```
^(?!www$).+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/d5oKof/1).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!www$)` - the string cannot be equal to `www`
- `.+` - 1 or more characters (other than a line break if you do not use a DOTALL modifier)

Comment: BTW, `(.+)(www)` matches any 1+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible up to the last `www` capturing that `www` into Group 1. So, you were not checking anything with this regex, it was just matching `www` on a line but not at the start of it.